# LINQ Scalar Operation

Tags: c#, linq

Out of curiosity. Can anyone come up with a way to integrate those remaining two lines of code with the LINQ operation?

```
var code = string.Format("{0:00000}{1:000000000}{2:0000000}", SelectedPreset.Prefix, i, SelectedPreset.Amount);

// calculate checksum
var checksum = code
    .Reverse()
    .Select((c, index) => new { IsOdd = (index & 1) == 1, Value = (int) Char.GetNumericValue(c) })
    .Select(x => x.IsOdd ? x.Value : x.Value*3)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);

var rounded = ((checksum + 10 - 1)/10)*10;
checksum = rounded - checksum;
```

Comment: why? it seems like it would just obfuscate what you're trying to do

Comment: Once you've done the aggregate you're not working with enumerations any more. You could wrap everything from code.Reverse to the .Aggregate in an Enumerable.Repeat, but it isn't going to make it any easier to read, quite the opposite actually.

Comment: Yes I know that @Binary. It's me being curious to learn something new. I am not looking into some funky way to force something into LINQ just for the sake of it.

Comment: This seems to be more suitable on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think this is a valid question. I don't see anything wrong with asking an academic, curiosity-based question to explore the capabilities of LINQ. That being said, @Andrew and Oliver, you should be having this discussion in Chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't. The code is pretty clear already. Why would you want to jump through hoops to end up with something that is going to be less readable?

Rename `checksum` though. Something like (you can come up with a better name; the point is to just not call the first calculation `checksum` if it's not actually the checksum):

```
var intermediate = // your LINQ expression
var rounded = ((intermediate + 10 -1) / 10) * 10;
var checksum = rounded - intermediate;
```

Also, change

```
IsOdd = (index & 1) == 1
```

to

```
IsIndexOdd = index % 2 != 0
```

And if you really must know:

```
 var checksum =
     new [] {
         code
            .Reverse()
            .Select((c, index) => new {
                IsIndexOdd = index % 2 != 0,
                Value = (int) Char.GetNumericValue(c)
            })
            .Select(x => x.IsIndexOdd ? x.Value : 3 * x.Value)
            .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b)
     }
     .Select(x => new { Rounded = ((x + 10 - 1) / 10) * 10, Intermediate = x })
     .Select(x => x.Rounded - x.Intermediate)
     .Single();
```

Don't do this.

Comment: Same response as to Binary Worker. This is a purely academical question. I was just curious to learn something new. I am not looking into some funky way to force something into LINQ just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Oliver Weichhold: Fine. See my edit. Do not do this. It causes kittens to die.

Comment: Why would he change the odd checker? His method is faster and he does not seem to care about redability. Also the "IsOdd" name pretty much explains what it is.

Comment: @Jason: This is exactly how I would have done it but never would :) But thanks for taking the time to confirm it.

Comment: @MrFox: The performance difference is beyond irrelevant here. The way I've proposed is more readable (I don't care if here cares about readability or not; he should) and is correct in all cases (testing the last bit can go wrong depending on the representation). `IsOdd` could be confused for the character being odd, or the numerical value of the character being odd; `IsIndexOdd` makes it more clear that we mean the index of the character in the string.

Comment: @Jason: You are right of course but since the scope of that variable is really limited only to the following line of code, I think this minor glitch is acceptable.

Comment: @Oliver Weichhold: Well, there are other ways. You could define myriad extension methods to achieve it in different ways (project a scalar, aggregate and then project, etc.). Again, hoops that make the code less clear. Don't do it.

Comment: @Jason i was referring to your remark about the naming of the IsOdd variable

Comment: @Oliver Weichhold: I was referring to your comment about "This is exactly how I would have done it" merely pointing out that it's not the only way. As for your comment about the `IsOdd` property; I disagree. More readable is more readable. Your future self will thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by defining your own extension method, not technically linq but sort of.  As Jason said, don't actually do this.

```
public static class CrazyExtension
{
    public S Project<T,S>(this T value, Func<T,S> Selector)
    {
        return Selector(value);
    }
}
```

This then lets you use:

```
 var checksum =
         code
         .Reverse()
         .Select((c, index) => new { IsOdd = (index & 1) == 1, Value = (int) Char.GetNumericValue(c) })
         .Select(x => x.IsOdd ? x.Value : x.Value*3)
         .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b)
         .Project(x => new { Rounded = ((x + 10 - 1) / 10) * 10, Intermediate = x })
         .Project(x => x.Rounded - x.Intermediate);
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

with

```
.Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + b, x => ((x + 10 - 1) / 10) * 10 - x);
```